# Java: Different return type by enum

Tags: java, generics, types, return

I want to know if it's possible to have multiple return types which are given by an enum parameter at the method.

For example:

```
public <T extends ICloudServer> T startServer(ServerType type) {
  ...
}
```

If the server type is PROXY, i want to return a ProxyServer, if the server type is MINECRAFT, i want to return a MinecraftServer.

Is there any way to realize this with Java?

Comment: Sure, but making the method generic is useless (and actually dangerous, since anyone could call it using `yourObject.<MinecraftServer>startServer(ServerType.PROXY)`. Make the method non-generic, and use ICloudServer as its return type.

Comment: Yeah, but what is the other solution for that?

Comment: Make the method non-generic, and use ICloudServer as its return type.

Comment: That's a solution, but I need the extra methods from the Proxy- and MinecraftServer and I think to cast the result every time is a little bit ugly.

Comment: If you know that what you absolutely want is a ProxyServer/MinecraftServer, then create two methods startProxy()/startMinecraft(). Not need to cast, no need to pass a generic type, no need to pass an enum value.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with casting, so long as you know the cast is safe.  If you have the class (`Class`) of the type you can even do a dynamic cast using the `cast` method on `Class`.  Effective Java shows a nice use case for dynamic casting.  Though in this case perhaps what you really need is the Factory pattern or one of the other creator patterns

Comment: Make all server type implements `ICloudServer` and return started server according to `ServerType`. As @JB Nizet mentioned return as `ICloudServer` instead of `<T extends ICloudServer> T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make servers implement `ICloudServer` interface and add `start` method into `ServerType` enum to be server starting-up *strategy* method. Different server has different configuration and  start up procedures.

```
class Minecraft implements ICloudServer{

    //ctor
    Minecraft(ServerConfig cfg){
         //ctor implementations
    } 

    //Other implementation details
}

public enum ServerType {

    MINECRAFT { 
        @Override
        public ICloudServer start(ServerConfig cfg ) {      
            //Apply config for minecraft
            Minecraft server = new Minecraft(cfg.port()).username(cfg.username()).password(cfg.password()).done();
             //Start minecraft server 
            server.start();
            return  server;
        }
    },

    PROXY {
        @Override
        public ICloudServer start(ServerConfig cfg) { 
            //Apply config and start proxy server
            ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(cfg);           
            return server;
        }
    };
    public abstract ICloudServer start(ServerConfig port) throws Exception;
}
```

As @JB Nizet mentioned change `startServer` method return type to `ICloudServer` and simply call `ServerType#start(ServerConfig cfg)` to start the server.

```
public ICloudServer startServer(ServerType type) {  

    try{
       return type.start(new ServerConfig());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //log exception
    }

    throw new ServerStartException("failed to start server");
}
```